# Cucumber with Serenity does not execute all scenarios with the same tags name

Tags: maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity

I'm using cucumber with serenity and want to execute 2 test scenarios with the same tag name. However, it just only run the first one. Could you please have a look?

**Cucumber class**

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"vn.auto", "cucumber.hook"}, features = "src/main/features", tags = {"@mytag"}, plugin = {"pretty"})
public class AppTest {
}
```

**Test scenario:**

```
@mytag
  Scenario: TEST 1
    Given User go to url "https://google.com/"
    When User search with text "selenium"
    Then BNPL - User should see text "Selenium"

  @mytag
  Scenario: TEST 2
    Given User go to url "https://google.com/"
    When User search with text "cucumber"
    Then BNPL - User should see text "Cucumber"
```

Maven goal:

```
clean verify serenity:aggregate "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @mytag"
```

After running maven, the test only executes "TEST 1" but not "TEST 2"

Comment: The correct command would be `mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@mytag"`

Comment: Hi,It is the same

Comment: Could you provide the maven log when running the command?

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't have compile error? `tags = {"@mytag"}` is incorrect. `tags` requires String, not an array of String, it should be `tags = "@mytag"`